# Java leaking this in constructor to the nested class

Tags: java, constructor, this

From previous discussion in StackOverflow, I know it is undesirable to pass *this* around before the constructor returns.

But what if we are passing *this* to the constructor of the inner class? Since inner class already have an implicit *this* pointer to the outer class, would explicitly passing *this* still be an issue?

One real example is in Apache Helix ([here](https://github.com/apache/helix/blob/dd05393cc354fdfc4407f781c6bfe024e19f5b07/helix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/helix/manager/zk/CallbackHandler.java#L122)).

Basically it is doing:

```
public class Outer
{
  public Outer() {
    new Thread(new Inner(this)).start();
  }

  class Inner implements Runnable {
    private Outer outer;
    Inner(Outer outer) {
       this.outer = outer;
    }

    public void run() {
      //some logic
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would it need to explicitly pass the reference? An inner class already implicitly has a reference to an enclosing instance. This is not a strict rule, it always depends on context.

Comment: If the inner class starts a thread before the outer class is completely constructed, and then makes reference to the outer instance, you probably have undefined behavior.  It is easy to shoot yourself in the foot, even though in the code you show it's probably OK.

Comment: @JimGarrison Are you referring to the Helix code or my code? And why it is probably OK?

Comment: I'm referring to the code you posted.  It looks OK because the outer constructor does nothing after instantiating the inner class.  However, as @SotiriosDelimanolis pointed out, the inner instance has an implicit reference to the outer class anyway.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am confused here as well. But let's say, without passing the reference explicitly, would it be unsafe to use the reference to the enclosing instance before the constructor returns ?

Comment: It *might* be. But your code doesn’t do that.